# How to log in to Skype via command line

Tags: skype, aws

I am aware of how to install Skype via command line - by adding the Canonical Partner repo and using apt-get.

However, how can I log in via the command line? There are two reasons I want to do this. First is down to this being Ubuntu Server with no connected monitor and no desktop window manager running (and I don't want one, this is running on AWS micro). Second is to automate login upon boot up.

The end goal here is to build a Skype bot using Skype4Py (a Python lib).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nice thought, but I think this is Microsoft's problem. If Microsoft haven't built a Skype command line for Linux, then Ubuntu (or any other disrto) cannot do much.

Comment: Was hoping this wasn't the case. I had my fingers crossed for a nice switch that handled it all. Not sure what I was thinking :(

Answer (score 2):

At least in version 4.2.0.11, there does appear to be such an option

```
$ skype --help
Skype 4.2.0.11

Usage: skype [options]
Options:
  --dbpath=       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                        Default: ~/.Skype
  --resources=    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                        Default: /usr/share/skype
  --secondary           Start a secondary instance of Skype.
  --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
  --callto 
  skype:?
                        These commands allow Skype links handling.
  --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
  --version             Display version information and exit.
```

```
$ skype --version
Skype 4.2.0.11
Copyright (c) 2004-2013, Skype
$
```

Comment: Awesome.  Will be sure to give this a go :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless X/GNOME is running, I guess Skype doesn't run unless it detects some sort of desktop environment.  I've bitten the bullet and just run it anyway :( thanks for the help though